# Using the self-parameter in python objects

Tags: python, class

I've got a question about defining functions and the self-parameter in python.

There is following code.

```
class Dictionaries(object):
    __CSVDescription = ["ID", "States", "FilterTime", "Reaction", "DTC", "ActiveDischarge"]

    def __makeDict(Lst):
        return dict(zip(Lst, range(len(Lst))))

    def getDict(self):
        return self.__makeDict(self.__CSVDescription)

    CSVDescription = __makeDict(__CSVDescription)

x = Dictionaries()
print x.CSVDescription
print x.getDict()
```

`x.CSVDescription` works fine. But `print x.getDict()` returns an error.

```
TypeError: __makeDict() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I can add the `self`-parameter to the `__makeDict()` method, but then `print x.CSVDescription` wouldn't work.

How do I use the `self`-parameter correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using `@staticmethod` won't work here because calling the method from the class body itself doesn't invoke the descriptor protocol (this would also be a problem for normal methods if they were descriptors - but that isn't the case until after the class definition has been compiled). There are four major options here - but most of them could be seen as some level of code obfuscation, and would really need a comment to answer the question "why not just use a `staticmethod`?".

The first is, as @Marcus suggests, to always call the method from the class, not from an instance. That is, every time you would do `self.__makeDict`, do `self.__class__.__makeDict` instead. This will look strange, because it is a strange thing to do - in Python, you almost never need to call a method as `Class.method`, and the only time you do (in code written before `super` became available), using `self.__class__` would be wrong.

In similar vein, but the other way around, you could make it a `staticmethod` and invoke the descriptor protocol manually in the class body - do: `__makeDict.__get__(None, Dictionaries)(__lst)`.

Or, you could detect yourself what context its being called from by getting fancy with optional arguments:

```
def __makeDict(self, Lst=None):
    if Lst is None:
       Lst = self
    ...
```

But, by far the best way is to realise you're working in Python and not Java - put it outside the class.

```
def _makeDict(Lst):
    ...

class Dictionaries(object):
   def getDict(self):
      return _makeDict(self.__CSVDescription)

   CSVDescription = _makeDict(__CSVDescription)
```

Comment: yes, you're right, i've made mistakes and i have deleted my answer.

Answer (score 6):

In python, the `self` parameter is implicitly passed to instance methods, unless the method is decorated with `@staticmethod`.

In this case, `__makeDict` doesn't need a reference to the object itself, so it can be made a static method so you can omit the `self`:

```
@staticmethod
def __makeDict(Lst): # ...

def getDict(self):
    return self.__makeDict(self.__CSVDescription)
```

Comment: But `CSVDescription = __makeDict(__CSVDescription)` doesn't work, when I add `@staticmethod`. Then I get the error `TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable`.

Comment: @wewa which Python version are you using?

Comment: I am using Python version 2.5.1